# How to split an excel file into multiple sheets if it has more than 255 rows?

Tags: python, sql, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file that contain 1009 columns. I am trying to insert the data from excel into sql server. However, I am getting error saying The statement has been terminated. (3621); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot create a row of size 8349 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.

How can I create a python script to split the excel file into multiple worksheets. For example, if there are 1000 columns, the code must split it into 4 worksheets based on the primary key which is the first column in excel. Below is my current code to insert the data from excel to sql:

```
def sqlcol(dfparam):    
    import sqlalchemy as sqla
    dtypedict = {}
    for i,j in zip(dfparam.columns, dfparam.dtypes):
        if "object" in str(j):
            dtypedict.update({i: sqla.types.NVARCHAR(length=255)})

        if "datetime" in str(j):
            dtypedict.update({i: sqla.types.DateTime()})

        if "float" in str(j):
            dtypedict.update({i: sqla.types.Float()})

        if "int" in str(j):
            dtypedict.update({i: sqla.types.BIGINT()})

    return dtypedict

def import_varchar_to_hst03(db:str,tb_name:str,df):
    import pandas as pd
    import sqlalchemy as sqla
    import urllib
    import pyodbc
    t=sqlcol(df)
    quoted = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE="+db+";Trusted_Connection=yes;")
engine = sqla.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted), fast_executemany = True)
df.to_sql(tb_name, schema='dbo', con = engine, index=False,dtype=t,if_exists='replace')


import pandas as pd

Ex=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\sriram.ramasamy\Desktop\Testsriram.xlsx',sheet_name=None)


for sh,v in Ex.items():
    df=pd.DataFrame(v)    
    import_varchar_to_hst03('InsightMaster',sh,df)

print('data imported to database')
```

Comment: Why do you want to split the excel? you can split the dataframe depends on the limit and you can insert the splitted dataframes

Comment: how do i do that? Sorry I am still new to python dataframe

Comment: can you help to alter the code i have posted? I am not really sure on how to split the dataframe by column count @deadshot

Comment: i have added this line of code  df = df.iloc[:,:255]  but not sure how to make it dynamic so it will create multiple tables @deadshot

Answer (score 0):

The issue your data has too many columns, It exceeded the maximum size of one row. One solution is to change `NVARCHAR` to `VARCHAR`
this will solve the problem.

> In the case of the VARCHAR data type, each character occupies 1 byte, while in the case of NVARCHAR, each character needs 2 bytes of storage, which means NVARCHAR is twice as expensive as VARCHAR.

```
def sqlcol(dfparam):    
    dtypedict = {}
    for i,j in zip(dfparam.columns, dfparam.dtypes):
        if "object" in str(j):
            dtypedict.update({i: sqla.types.VARCHAR(length=255)})

        if "datetime" in str(j):
            dtypedict.update({i: sqla.types.DateTime()})

        if "float" in str(j):
            dtypedict.update({i: sqla.types.Float()})

        if "int" in str(j):
            dtypedict.update({i: sqla.types.BIGINT()})

    return dtypedict
```

So if you update your column datatype from `NVARCHAR` to `VARCHAR` It will work.

Even after changing if it still doesn't work you need to normalize your data/remove unused columns.

Comment: nope still the same error saying Cannot create a row of size 8349 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060

Comment: There are only 763 rows but 1000+ columns

Comment: Ok got it. Thank you. As you said i need to normalize the data and will think a way for it.